# Java patten draw within for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am very new in the programming world and in Javaland too. 
I am trying to learn for loop and solving pattern with it.

I want to draw this pattern using for loop :

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I am using this code to achieve this:

```
public class PatterWithForLoop {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
            System.out.println("*" + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

But, I am only getting * in 15 lines, not in the pattern. 
Please, anyone can help to solve this issue here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show a bit more context. That `for` loop shouldn't run any iteration at all.

Comment: It is iterating but I am not getting an expected output.

Comment: That code does not produce the output you are describing.

Comment: Hint: search the doc for the difference between `print` and `println`.

Comment: Thanks Serge. Khelwood, I have updated my code with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i, j, n =5;  
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) {           
            for(j=0; j<=i; j++) {       
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Som. That's works. I never thought for loop inside for loop. Sorry, I tried to tick your answer but I don't have enough reputation to do it. Will accept it later Thanks.

Comment: @NipamPatel : Welcome bro !

Answer (score 4):

If you are using JDK 11, you can write the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.println("*".repeat(i+1));
}
```

With [String.repeat()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)), you can do the same thing with less code.

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop seems strange.

The loop should be read like this:

"For `int` `i` starting at `0`, loop **as long as** `i<5` and **after** every iteration, do `i++`"

```
for(int i = 0; i<5, i++){
   System.out.println("*" \n);
}
```

This will print 5 rows:

```
*

*

*

*

*
```

now in every row you want one more `*` and you might want to remove the `\n` which is already included in `println`
So instead of printing `"*"` you create a `String` before the loop and you add one new `*` to it every iteration:

```
String line ="";             // we start with an empty string
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){      
   line= line+"*";           // before printing we add a new *
   System.out.println(line); // then we print it 
}
```

It should (haven't tested it) result in this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: I am trying to give tick your answer but not able to do as I don't have enough reputation but I will do it later. Thanks.